# When I try to save data to Firebase it only updates the existing data, Swift, Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The way I set up my database structure was like this:

It starts with Lists then there is a child that shows the users UID then inside that there is one item.

[image]

The one item inside the UID gets updated every time I attempt to save new data. Instead of adding another item the same one just keeps changing. I was wondering how I could instead of update the same one item every time add more items.

The way that I save my data is with this line of code.

```
let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
let item: String = self.ItemTextField.text!
self.ref.child("Lists").child(user!.uid).setValue(["Items": item])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More idiomatic is to store the list of items with so-called push ids:

```
Lists
  twEymn...
    -Km....: "Yoghurt"
```

You'd do this with:

```
self.ref.child("Lists").child(user!.uid).childByAutoId().setValue(item)
```

The `childByAutoId()` generates a unique, sequential ID. It's similar to an array index, but this one works reliably in multi-user environments and when users can be offline. Read this [blog post about these so-called push ids](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html).

Alternatively you can use the name of the item as the key (if the item has to be unique in the list):

```
Lists
  twEymn...
    "Yoghurt": true
```

In that case the code becomes:

```
self.ref.child("Lists").child(user!.uid).child(item).setValue(true)
```

One thing you'll note is that both of these approaches only deal with the newly added item, instead of the list of items as a whole. This is a general pattern you'll see when using Firebase. By isolating your modifications, your app will be more scalable without users getting into each other's way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting a key-value pair ("Items" : item) so that each time it is updating the value for the same key. What you could do instead is ("Items" : [your array of items here]), which will update a list of items for the same key each time.

You could also fetch the current list of items, append your new item locally, and then update.